# Should a Moderator's actions be publicly visible?

Tags: discussion

This would fit into [open/transparent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_%28behavior%29) behaviour.

Possible pros of such change might be:

1. Appreciation of large amount of work done,
2. Better overall public knowledge about such amount,
3. Action types might get quantified and later lay foundations to Stack Overflow Academy
4. A healthy competition might take place

Cons:

1. In case of (rare) Moderator mistake, some lawful person might commit a chaotic act of creating question, and demanding justice,
2. Moderators might feel judged or watched, which could impede their actions
3. Healthy competition might quickly turn into unhealthy one, lowering standards.

Comment: What moderator actions which are currently public are you considering hiding, respectively which actions that are currently private do you want to see publicised?

Comment: I imagine that all (subset?) actions regarding usage of special permissions (ie. non-acessible to normal users regardless of reputation) could be public, for example: count or explicit link to deletions/move's, whereas actions that normal user can do - and are hidden - would remain hidden.

Comment: Deletions aren't hidden to 10k+ users, they're right there with the moderator's name on them. So are closings, they are visible to all. Flag-handling can hardly be made public without giving away who flagged, and what, and why, all pretty much no-nos because they involve users, not just the moderator. You'll have to be more clear what exactly you want made transparent.

Comment: Yes questions are, where they where, but they are not aggregated by particular Moderator. This would mean that any user might see, what job had been done by particular Moderator.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's no need for this.

1. Moderator actions are already reviewed by the other moderators and the community managers. If we make a mistake it's quickly corrected.
2. We are often dealing with users private information, having all our actions in public would reveal this information.
3. While security by obscurity isn't ideal, there's no point in making the lives of spammers and trolls easier by revealing how we go about spotting them and banning them from the sites.
4. We have private moderator stats pages so we already know how much work we do compared to the other moderators. It's not a game, but there is some competition between moderators from time to time. However, the last thing we want to do is encourage that, as it *could* lead to hasty decisions being taken just to get the flag handling numbers up, and hasty decisions are often bad decisions.
5. I think most users have an appreciation of what we do already.
6. Users that ended up on the wrong side of the moderators should be given a second chance after receiving their warning or having served their temporary suspension. Airing the moderator actions would run counter to this. (shamelessly stolen from Martijn)

Comment: 6. Users that ended up on the wrong side of the moderators should be given a second chance after receiving their warning or having served their temporary suspension. Airing the moderator actions would run counter to this.

Comment: 1-that I'm aware. Still, I find it improbable to review all actions, as it would duplicate work exponentially. 5-please don't take this question as an attack, it is not. Nor have I any complaint, just an observation. If content matters, shouldn't deletion be rare/last action to take, since questions with many downvotes are ignored by Community anyway?

Comment: +1 I agree, I think any long time user exposed to the day to day workings of the site has a fair idea of how much work moderators do. I don't think there is a problem being solved by revealed each individual action, and the potential for villainizing users would be undesirable.

Comment: So perhaps it's greater good :-) / lesser evil. By that I mean hypotetical situation where rare mistake (flag/action/no-action) gets past second review, compared to quite possible harm by full-disclosure. I haven't found any guidelines when to accept an answer on meta, so I'm accepting this one.